# System hangs when computing gradients on GPU with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, ubuntu-16.04

#### Problem description

My system hangs when I compute gradients on my GPU.  I am able to compute gradients on my CPU without any issues.  I can compute all the nodes in my graph, including my loss function, on my GPU without issue.  My system hangs when I compute gradients on my GPU irrespective of which optimizer I use.  The code that produces this issue is:

```
sess = tf.Session()

# ...

cnn = CNNClass()

#...

step_size = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="step_size") 
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False) 
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(step_size, 0.9)

#...

# CRASHES WHEN I RUN THIS
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cnn.loss)
sess.run([grads_and_vars], feed_dict)

# DOES NOT CRASH WHEN I RUN THIS
sess.run([cnn.loss])
```

#### Further details

I tried setting `gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)` in my ConfigProto but that didn't help.

Launching `watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi` before running the code shows Volatile GPU-Util goes to 100% just before hanging.

Computing gradients on my CPU and printing them out shows normal output (I'm not getting any NaNs or 0's or anything like that).

#### System information

- System: Ubuntu 16.04
- TensorFlow installed from: binary
- TensorFlow version: v1.0.0-65-g4763edf-dirty 1.0.1
- CUDA version: 8.0, V8.0.61
- cuDNN version: 5.1
- GPU model and memory: NVidia GeForce GTX TITAN X (12GB)
- Video card driver: 375.39

#### EDIT 1: Update

The code runs on the GPU after scaling down the model.

There appears to be significant overhead in starting computations on the GPU.  I can see this when I train an intermediate-size model: Volatile GPU-Util goes to 100%  for a while without completing any evaluations, then Volatile GPU-Util drops to around %30 and the evaluation loop begins running fairly quickly.  This wouldn't be an issue except for the fact that my system is almost completely unusable until Volatile GPU-Util drops back down to 30%.

I assume overhead is somehow associated with putting data on the GPU.  Can someone explain why this happens?  Is there a way to prevent TensorFlow from hogging all Volatile GPU during the upstart phase?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow works best when given full control of the GPU. To avoid the system hanging when it is using it fully the easiest thing to do is to not use your GPU for graphics when using it for training.